# Java mail. How to check if login was successful?

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

I have this class, that handles login to gmail. Program returns session no matter what email and password I enter. I don't understend how to check if login is successful before returning session object.

```
package mailActions;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.*;

public class Login {

    static Properties props = new Properties();

    public static Session login(final String username, final String password) {
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });

        return session;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've used javamail but I would use the session's getProperties() method and then iterate through the properties to see if there is an available property you can leverage to solve this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Session object just represents the configuration information you're using with JavaMail.  You actually need to connect to a server to find out if you have the correct credentials.  Use the Store.connect or Transport.connect methods, depending on what you're trying to do.